# Passenger Standalone after Version 5.1.12 Issues / Nginx / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Using Passenger Standalone on version 5.1.12 works just fine. All the routes to rails and it's specified ports in nginx configs pull up great.

But after that version, the app's routing returns a 404. Also subsequent reload causes images to go missing. Then back again tot he routing 404 on the next reload.

Has anyone faced the same issue and any solutions out there?

Comment: could you share your nginx config? With the current info it's impossible to help you solve the issue